# Redirect non existing page to Default Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, url, alternate-access-mapping, redirect

I have a Sharepoint Foundation 2013 running for nearly 2 years now and its primary URL is http://sharepoint.mycompany.com, all is working fine.

Then toady we migrated and merged our company intranet to this Sharepoint Instance and I added a new Alternate Access Mapping called http://intranet.mycompany.com, this also works fine it resolves to http://sharepoint.mycompany.com.

The problem is when a user have a bookmark in their browser like http://intranet.mycompany.com/SignIn.aspx or http://intranet.mycompany.com/Something.aspx it does not do anything, how do I handle this situation, meaning how would I redirect those to just http://sharepoint.mycompany.com

Comment: http://intranet.mycompany.com/Something.aspx should be http://intranet.mycompany.com/Pages/Default.aspx or something like this. Don't know how did You migrate, but if You say it's Ok in AAM, there could be something with IIS bindings..

Comment: I think the easiest solution will be to have people update their bookmarks. The existing bookmarks are looking for specific pages, yet those pages no longer exist because your old URL is redirecting to the new one. An alternate option would be to create pages at those locations, but have those pages merely redirect. It's sloppy, and high-maintenance, but it would work as long as you know the names of the pages they're looking for.

Comment: Hi Omegacron looks like this is the path I am looking at now